# Collections View with drop down menu

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I wish to create a drop down menu which will only appear at the spot where the blank empty space is when the 'seasonal' tab is selected and remain hidden when the 'Latest' tab is selected.

How do I achieve that?

viewController image:

[image]

Do I have to use `UISearchDelegeate` for this?

Edit: how to make the headerView of the collectionsView respond to the segmented control buttons up top: "Latest and Seasonal"? For eg. when "Latest" is selected, the header view will resize to width: 0, height: 0 and when "Seasonal" is selected, the header will be resized to width: 320 and height: 50?

Here's an example, but so far my code is wrong. I'm not sure how to return CGSize.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        if segmentedControlValue.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            let size = CGSize (width: 0, height: 50)
        }
        if segmentedControlValue.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            let size = CGSize (width: 0, height: 0)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func selectionButtons(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        collectionView?.reloadData()

    }
```

here's the new code I just added:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let selectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "selectionCell", for: indexPath)

        if toggleState.currentTitle == "View" {
            selectionCell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 100)
        }
        if toggleState.currentTitle == "NoView" {
            selectionCell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        }
        return selectionCell
```

Comment: cant get your ques properly ?

Comment: Ok, I've updated it with a code.

Comment: you want to make it as a part of collectionView of free to use uiview for that ?

Comment: Free to use UI view. If possible, I wanna make one of those sticky headers which drops down when you tap on settings to allow you to edit the filter for data to be parsed before reloading the collection view. That's the general gist of it.

Comment: check my ans and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `collectionView` `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method to handle header with `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` and footer with `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter` kind view.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "myHeaderView", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        // configure header view

        if segmentedControlValue.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
             view.frame = // set frame
        }
        if segmentedControlValue.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
             view.frame = // set frame
        }

        return view
}
```

So when you call `reloadData()` method this takes as a part of execution and you can take appropriate action to `view` inside.

Comment: Nope still doesnt work, I've edited my post to include the code that I just added.

Comment: @Lerws there is bit small mistakes as you can see.. just add `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` as a suppview and give width as 320 or dynamic where you given 100 height to that view inside first if condition so view can be visible or use mine code exactly.

Comment: Comment your `collectionViewLayout` method while using my code, you are almost done.